# Regex — Match Range but only once per unique character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to avoid arrays and loops by using a regex range, however, i only want to replace the first instance of each character in the range once.

I'm using range because I can't guarantee order and can't re-order.

For example:

`"access".replace(/[access]/g, '') = "cs", instead of "".
"cell phones".replace(/[el]/g) = "cl phones", instead of "c phons"`

Doubles in the regex range are redundant anyways, and in this instance, it should also not cause the second occurrence to be replaced.

If this is not possible, then I'll have to think of something else.

Comment: You can cache the characters removed and prevent further removal, the second parametter to replace will be a function instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a look-behind--to see if the character has occurred earlier and should therefore be retained. But JS does not support that. Search for "JS look-behind regexp" for some ideas. The classic approach is to reverse the string so you can use look-aheads:

```js
const rev = s => s.split('').reverse().join('');

const testData = [
  ["access", 'access'],
  ["cell phones", 'el']
];

function match(s, chrs) {
  const reg = new RegExp(`([${chrs}])(?!.*\\1)`, "g");
  return rev(rev(s).replace(reg, ''));
}
  
testData.forEach(([input, chrs]) => console.log("input", input, "gives", match(input, chrs)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example of what I said in the comment above:

```js
function replace(str, regex) {
  var cache = {};          // the cache object
  return str.replace(regex, function(m) {
    if(cache[m]) return m; // if we already removed an instance of this matched character then don't remove any further instances
    
    // otherwise ...
    cache[m] = true;       // cache the character
    return '';             // remove it
  });
}

console.log('"access", /[access]/g => ', replace("access", /[access]/g));
console.log('"cell phones", /[el]/g => ', replace("cell phones", /[el]/g));
```

**Note:** Assuming that the regular expression passed are all just character sets (ranges as you call them), just `/[...]/g` are allowed, or the behavior is won't be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Single line version of "remembering" logic.

```
"cell phones".replace(/[el]/g, (() => { let seen = []; return m => seen.includes(m) ? m : (seen.push(m),''); })())
```

A shorter version:

```
"cell phones".replace(/[el]/g, (seen => m => m in seen ? m : seen[m] = ''))({}))
```

Comment: the entire jQuery library is a oneliner... Rather make your code readable

Comment: If you want to write short code, why are you not using the concise body form of arrow functions? You also do not need parentheses around a single parameter. So `a => b` instead of `(a) => { return b; }`.